# Dynamic namespaces for XmlElement with JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

I use JAXB marshaller to convert Java classes to XML MRSS files. It looks something like that:

```
public class RssBuilder {
    public void saveToFile( RSS rss, String fileName ) {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance( RSS.class );
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty( Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true );

        NamespacePrefixMapper mapper = namespaceMapper;
        marshaller.setProperty( "com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper", mapper );

        marshaller.setProperty( Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true );
        fos = new FileOutputStream( fileName );
        marshaller.marshal( rss, fos );
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
public class RSS {
    @XmlElement( name = "channel" )
    public List<RssChannel> getChannels() {return channels;}    
}

public class RssChannel {
    @XmlElement( name = "item" )
    private List<RssItem> items;
    public void setItems( List<RssItem> items ) { this.items = items; }
    public void addItem( RssItem item ) { this.items.add( item ); }
    ....
}

public class RssItem {
    @XmlElement (name = "description", namespace=RSS.YAHOO_XMLNS)   
    private MediaTitle mediaDescription;

    @XmlElement (name ="origReleaseDate", namespace=RSS.BING_XMLNS)
    private String origReleaseDate;
    ....
}
```

There are two MRSS formats by YAHOO and by BING. BING MRSS is almosts similar and just adding some additional elements to YAHOO scheme, so I use two namespaces in elements annotations. The problem that in such way YAHOO MRSS files are also contain xmnls attribute for BING schema although there is no 'bing' elements. I can solve it creating separate RSS root element classes, but it will cause creating separate classes for channel and item elements too.

Is there simplier way to solve this?

Comment: Hi Even I am looking for something like this where I have to provide the `namespace` to `@XmlElement` dynamically. Do you remember how you did this?